# set_checkbox for multiple select checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

how to set checkbox value if form validation fails in codeigniter. I have multiple select checkbox whose values populated from other dropdown selection. I want if form validation fails it should give me selected values. In my case it disappers. Any help will be appreciated.
my code:

```
<tbody class="location_id">
<?
    $checked='';
    if(isset($data1['loc_id']))
    { 
        if($data1['loc_id']!='')
        {
            $checked='checked';
        }
    }
    if(isset($data1['loc_id'])){
?>

    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="loc_id[]" value="<?php  if(isset($data1['loc_id'])){ echo $data1['loc_id'];} ?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('loc_id[]', $data1['loc_id']); ?> <?php echo $checked;?>></td><td><?php  if(isset($data1['loc_id'])){echo get_name('location_tbl','loc_id',$data1['loc_id'],'loc_name');}?></td></tr>

<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

hope you understand.
In my controller I have set

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('loc_id', '', 'trim|xss_clean');
```

sorry for grammar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox"    style= "position: initial;" name="hobby[]"  value="Sport"<?php if(strpos($hobby, 'Sport') !== false) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> >Sport
```

model:-

```
$hobby =implode(",", $this->input->post('hobby'));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.